# OpenVZ veth interface error

Tags: ping, ipv6, openvz

I'm trying to setup my openvz containers to use a veth interface.

I have veth1.0 on the host node and I see eth0 in the vz. but when I do:

```
ip -6 route add 2001:249a:aaa1:0000:0000:0000:0001:0001/112 dev veth1.0
```

on the host node and i type

```
ping6 2001:249a:aaa1:0000:0000:0000:0001:0001
```

it doesn't ping??

Comment: Have you assigned 2001:249a:aaa1::1:1 to any interface? Just having a route to the /112 prefix doesn't magically assign the address to an interface. And where are you pinging from?

Answer (score 0):

Enable IPv6 forwarding:

```
cat 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/forwarding
```

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't assign a full /112??

Comment: Shouldn't that be `echo 1`?